# Getting fsck not done error during boot

Tags: macos

During starting up, I always get "fsck not done   Root device is    mounted read-only..." error. When I type "Exit", it continues starts normally.

[image: error image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are not holding down the <kbd>s</kbd> key while booting then your NVRAM has a flag set or the keyboard has failed and is signaling that the key is pressed.

Try disconnecting USB keyoard at boot or [resetting the NVRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379) so that the normal boot proceeds.

Should that not work, you'll have to proceed with an odd-ball article followed by the general "Mac fails to start" article:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4376
- http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2570